# Android plug-in

Tags: android, google-play

My application will have a low cost for a basic version.
If the user need more features, heneed to buy plug-in.

**Question is:
What is the best solution for this approach?**

Better the use of in-app billing or publish packet that contain the plug-in as normal apps with a price ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In-app billing is the recommended means for providing extra features. There's very little to worry about with it, as it's all taken care of through google play functionality. Otherwise you're requiring your users to download a whole new apk file as a paid for thing.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) page on the Android Developer site gives a good set of instructions on how to achieve this.